# Failed to parse the output of 'adb version' - every solution didn't work

Tags: android, adb

I'm running Eclipse Indygo, android 2.2 and 2.3 - this project is in 2.2
 and latest update of **java se update 29**
I was reading a lot of post with the very same issue, but after did what was told to do nothings happend, here is what i got:
First i get this error:

```
[2011-10-23 12:53:42 - adb]Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'
```

And later:

```
[2011-10-23 12:58:13 - tes] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2011-10-23 12:58:13 - tes] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2011-10-23 12:58:13 - tes] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\dobryandroid\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

And what I've already did:
-copy content to tools directory
-update java
-start *adb kiil-server/start server* 
-i sure that the adb exist and can be executed
So i did generally eveything was said here
Have you got any other suggestions how to solve that issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the `sdk\platform-tools` contents to `sdk\tool` **NOT** `sdk\tools`

I'm running debian so the following worked for me: (within the sdk directory)

```
ln -s platform-tools/ tool
```